# Execte a c++ program when ethernet wire is plugin

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, networking

I have a very simple c++ program that log in to my institute network. I have made the executable a.out.Its working but I have to execute the program.Now I want to run the program a.out whenever I plugin my Ethernet wire automatically.

Comment: OK - so what is your question and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have a very simple c++ program that log in to my institute network. I have made the executable a.out.Its working but I have to execute the program.Now I want to run the program a.out whenever I plugin my Ethernet wire automatically.

Comment: @Anshuman: That doesn't answer the "what have you tried" part *at all!*

Comment: @MSalters I was having no idea where to start, that is why I asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript

The idea is to run a program (the above says "script" but no matter) whenever the network interface status changes (becomes "up" in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Write a bash script and put it into '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/'

```
#!/bin/bash

IF=$1
STATUS=$2

if {[ "$IF" == "eth0" ] || [ "$IF" == "wlan0" ]}
then
    if "$2" == up
        # Command to run your C++ Program here.
        ;;    
    fi
fi
```